# Download and Sideload Production Metro App (Win8)

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store-app

I am not talking about an app you make.  I know the tricks to obtain a developer key or self sign the app and sideload it using a pseudo DC.  I am talking about production store apps.  There are some store apps I want to try but for privacy reasons I do not want to bind my computer to a particular MS account.  I much prefer to google the app files (free ones obviously), download them, and sideload them myself.  Are there any sites that host these?  I have found a bunch for ipks and apks, but not appx.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to download ans sideload apps from the store. You can only use the self signing hack.

Comment: Yes, but can you self sign a pre-packaged .appx file (where you do not have the source)

Comment: that's what I mean with the sign hack. I don't know any other way